# C++ How to include a third party library into your library without compiling it?

Tags: c++

I am building my first C++ library (header-only) and I want to include a third party library like `Crypto++`. Now I believe I am supposed to compile the `Crypto++` library and put the compiled archive inside the `./lib` directory and pass the linker commands when compiling my library. But since I do not want to compile the 3rd party library for every OS and I am building a header-only library I would like to include the 3rd party library without compiling it. Is there a way to I achieve this? BTW the `Crypto++` library is not a header-only library.

The hierarchy of my project is as follows:

```
ProjectName/
    ./include/
        ./ProjectName/
           ...
        ./internal/
            ./cryptopp/
               ... source files ...
    ./lib/
```

When I try to include `internal/cryptopp/sha.h` without passing the linker arguments to the compiled library it throws the `Undefined symbol ...` errors as expected. Is there a way I can achieve this? Or is there no other way than compiling the library and putting the compiled archive inside the `./lib/` dir and passing the correct linker arguments?

I am aware that this is quite a newbie question, I have just never done this before and C++ is still quite new for me.

Comment: You could get the library in a compile form...

Comment: @ChrisMM Though this is compiled with a certain debug and optimization level. And I can not find a compiled form of CryptoPP on their website or anywhere else.

Comment: Unless the third party-library has its own header-only library, then the end user will be required to link anyway. If you have a "header only" library, then realistically it shouldn't be depending on anything that needs to be compiled and linked ... Defeats the purpose (just imo)

Comment: It is a dependency and crypto++ in particular is not really a friendly one as it does not include even a cmake build configuration. You should keep the two separated as much as you could, that is what I do. My two cents here.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Do you mean separated like leave it to the user to install Crypto++ or just avoid using the 3rd party library at all?

Comment: nv mind I thought you were distributing your code as binaries. It looks like opensource so the answer below holds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are developing a header-only, platform-independent C++ library that happens to depend on a traditional (i.e. not header-only) C++ library, but which is also portable to a wide range of target platforms.

What you need to tell your users is that your library depends on that other library (crypto++ in this case), and ask them to install this library before attempting to use your header-only library, and to also link against crypto++ when compiling executables or libraries that use your library.

Do not distribute the crypto++ source code yourself as part of your library, because your users should and will want to update the crypto++ library that they use whenever it receives an update, independent of your library. This is especially important with regard to cryptography libraries because of the possible security implications.

Comment: Allright! Is this not considered bad practice? Since the user has to install other libraries as well? Or is that just how it works? And how about `openssl` same there? Since this is in fact a header-only library.

Comment: Not only is this good practice, but operating systems/distributions employ a package managing framework that manages these dependencies automatically. If your library gets built correctly then installing it, using the native package manangement software, will automatically install all of its dependencies too. See your operating system/distribution's technical documentation for more information.

Comment: @user283487, The proposed solution sounds acceptable to me. You can additionally provide an installer that takes care of ensuring all dependencies get installed together with your library.

Comment: Mayby some of your users will consider it bad practice, but especially with crypto libraries, you do not have another choice and you are doing your users a favor. (More people will definitely complain about your library if you do include potentially outdated crypto library sources)

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer above says, the primary method is to make an advice that your project has a dependency on a 3rd party library.

That said, another option that most projects use when in need of 3rd party projects is to use [git submodules](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). There is a [nice tutorial from Github](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/).

With git submodules, your git repository will only contain your own code but also will have a reference to an external git repository (to be placed in your 'lib' folder). Then when the user clones your repository, git will (optionally) bring into all the 3rd party libraries as well.

Another interesting mechanism to bring 3rd party projects at compile time is [CMake ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). It will download and build a github project at compile time for you so only apply to very small dependencies.

One such example is a regex performance shootout that brings in tons of 3rd party, small libraries and uses both methods:

https://github.com/rust-leipzig/regex-performance