# Is there a way to use GLFW without compiling It?

Tags: c++, glfw

I am writing a C++ header only library which is supposed to use GLFW but on the official site there is nothing said about being able to use it without compiling it first.

I thought about includeing all GLFW files from src folder but most of them are .C files so I can't really do that. Or should I just leave GLFW as a git submodule and make user link it to their project like suggested in this question [C++ How to include a third party library into your library without compiling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73940236/c-how-to-include-a-third-party-library-into-your-library-without-compiling-it)

So I'm asking is there a way to do that and if not what do you propose I should do?

Comment: GLFW is not something you drop in to a project like a JSON parser. It requires significant work to integrate it. Therefore it is fine to move the work of linking to GLFW to the people integrating your library.

Comment: You should list GLFW as a dependency of you library and let the user provide it.

Comment: Don't add GLFW as a submodule. Don't do anything at all, just include the header and expect the user to provide it. Document that the user must have GLFW installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going comply to all of your advice and make the user provide GLFW and link it to their project.

Thanks Everyone for your feedback.

Comment: Not an answer. Should be a comment